# Time trigger end of months

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

as the end of months varies from 30 to 31 and I have to set up a time trigger to trigger another function. if I input the 31 of all months, will it work on the 30?

here is my code

```
function timerTrigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('codeTrigger')
.timeBased()
.onMonthDay(31)
.atHour(23)
.inTimezone('Indian/Mauritius')
.create()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will calculate the days in each month for you.

```
function timerTriggerForLastDayInCurrentMonth() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('codeTrigger')
    .timeBased()
    .onMonthDay(daysInThisMonth())
    .atHour(23)
    .inTimezone('Indian/Mauritius')
    .create()
}

function daysInThisMonth() {
  const m = new Date().getMonth();//calculate the month for current date which is Jan - Dec 0 - 11
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), m + 1, 0).getDate();//add 1 to the month and set the day of the month to zero and it gives the number of days in the previous month which is the current month since one was added to it
}
```